# PowerShell + SharePoint cannot seem to add an assembly

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, powershell

I am having an issue 'using' a custom field I have created.  In power shell, the assembly is being loaded into the script using the LoadFrom function, and it throws no errors in loading the assembly, yet it acts as if the assembly wasn't loaded.

When trying to enumerate fields, I will get a 'not installed properly' error on one of my custom fields.  When trying to access a custom field via myListItem["myCustomField"] I get a CannotIndex error.

**I get these same errors when writing the exact code in Visual Studio with C#, however, once I add the reference to my assembly it works fine there.** (Important part here, this should indicate that I am not doing anything incorrectly in power shell, i.e. accessing the field by its display name rather than internal name etc).

If I add my assembly to the GAC, everything works fine in power shell, but this is not an option for me at the moment.  I need to be able to load the assembly from the dll.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An assembly loaded via LoadFrom does not behave the same way as one loaded from the GAC. It's more than just trust issues. If you have the patience, start here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/choosing-a-binding-context.aspx

Adding a reference in visual studio is just for the compilation process, not the runtime loading. At runtime, the the dependent assemblies (references) are placed in the same directory as the process executable (if they were not GAC references.) In the powershell case, your dependent assemblies are not in the same location as the process executable (powershell.exe). This is why probing for their dependencies fails. If you copied them into $PSHOME it would probably work, but this is not a workable solution as this is a privileged location under system32.

-Oisin

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  Copying it into $PSHOME does work, but you're right that it isn't something we would be able to do.. it is a good lead, though.

Comment: Well, it doesn't solve our problem since we can't put the assembly in $PSHOME.  Should I take away that my assembly must either be in the GAC or within the same folder as powershell.exe in order for it to be referenced properly?

Comment: @ferr - yes, that was the implication. One last thing you could try is loading manually dependencies first with add-type (i.e. reverse order) with your primary being loaded last and test that before accepting. You're dealing with fundamental security behaviour of the CLR here, not powershell/sharepoint glitches.

Comment: I just ran into this article where people are having similar problems.  They don't seem to find a solution that hasn't already been addressed here: http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/10/27/load-a-custom-dll-from-powershell/

Comment: @ferr - yes. Lee is one of the core developers in Microsoft for powershell.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell 2:

```
Add-Type -Path C:\Path\To\Assembly.dll
```

PowerShell 1:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom('C:\Path\To\Assembly.dll')
```

Comment: Using the PS2 version.. Does it need quotes? Using this, same result: Add-Type -Path 'C:\path\name\here\fields.dll'

Comment: I believe quotes would be optional, but they can't hurt.

Comment: Quotes aren't needed unless there's a space in the path.

Comment: I have the same problem with either of these methods.

Comment: Since this all works for me in C# when adding a reference in VS, I wonder what method it uses to add an assembly.. and if there's an equivalent process that I can use in PS..

Comment: @ferr - I've added some more detail to my answer.